# Best approach to delete a set of entries in a Map

Tags: java

Is there any fast and reliable way/approach to remove a set of entries based on an attribute on the entry's value. Below approach loops every entry which in undesirable.
e.g: ConcurrentHashMap  -  Entries will be in millions

```
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, POJO>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, POJO>> it = iterator; it.hasNext(); ) {
        Map.Entry<String, POJO> entry = it.next();
        POJO value = entry.getValue();
        if (value != null && *attribute*.equalsIgnoreCase(value.getAttribute())) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Databases handle these sorts of things by using _indexes_. So, you could have an another data structure to keep track of POJO identifiers having a certain attribute, or then have different maps that partition the data by attribute. But doing this easily complexifies things. Have you measured and identified this as a bottleneck in your application?

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way of mutating map in place without utilizing additional data structures. What you are basically asking for is secondary index like employed in databases, where you have pointers to entries based on some non-primary key properties. If you don't want to store extra index, there is no easier way then to iterate through all entries.

What I would suggest you to look into is composing map view over your original map. For example something like (using guava)

```
Map<String,POJO> smallerMap = Maps.filterValues(map, 
    v -> !attribute.equalsIgnoreCase(v.getAttribute())
);
```

You will need to be careful with such view (don't call size() on it for example), but for access etc it should be fine (depending on your exact needs, memory constraints etc).

And side note - please note I have removed null check for value. You cannot store null values in ConcurrentHashMap - and it is also not that great idea in normal map as well, better to remove entire key.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! The data maintained in the map is used as source data for another process. So the data should be removed. Multiple add, delete and update request will be there for the data on Map. So the view you are suggesting doesn't help this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions that I can think of

**First solution:**

Create another map for storing the object hashcode as key and corresponding key as value. The structure could be like as below

```
Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
```

Here is working solution. Only drawback of this is getting a unique hashcode might be tough if there are large number of objects.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DualHashMap {

    public static void main(String a[]){

        Map<String, Pojo> map = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();

        Pojo object1 = new Pojo();
        Pojo object2 = new Pojo();
        map.put( "key1", object1);
        map.put( "key2", object2);

        map2.put(object1.hashCode(), "key1");
        map2.put(object2.hashCode(), "key2");

        // Now let say you have to delete object1 you can do as follow
        map.remove(map2.get(object1.hashCode()));
    }
}


class Pojo{

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return  super.hashCode(); //You must work on this yourself, and make sure hashcode is unique for each object
    }

}
```

**2nd solution:-**

Use the solution provided for dual hashmap by Guava or Apache

The Apache Commons class you need is [BidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html).

Here is another for you by [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)

Comment: 1) Why involving hashcode in here? OP wants to have getAttribute indexed, not hashcode. 2) You cannot hope for attribute to be unique - you need to use something like Multimap, not bidirectional map. 3) Not sure what you wanted to show by doing `return this.hashCode()`, but as given it will go into infinite loop. Maybe you meant parent.hashCode()? (not that it makes a lot of sense anyway)

Comment: I have said- hascode could be one of the way. I am sure OP is not using hashcode any where else. Just see the comments of implementation of hashcode method  I have clearly written about it in comment. If user is maintaining id for POJO, it will be best choice of return of hashCode method.